# Debugging Transformer Errors in Mirth Connect Server Log

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

Fairly new to Mirth, so looking for advice in regards to debugging/getting more information from errors reported in the Server Log in Mirth Connect.  I know what channel this is originating from, but that's about it.  This error is received 10 times for each message coming through.  It should be noted that the channel is working properly except for this error cluttering up the logs.

**The Error:**

```
ERROR (transformer:?): TypeError: undefined is not an xml object.
```

**What I've Tried:**

- Ruled out Channel Map variables (mappers), they don't have null default values, they match up with vars in the incoming xml message, even changed to Javascript transformers to modify the catch to try to narrow down the issue, but no luck.
- Modified external javascript source files to include more error handling (wrapped each file in a try/catch that would log with identifying info) but this didn't change the result at all.
- Added a new Alert to send info if errors are received, but this alert never fired.

Anything else to try?  Thanks for any/all help!

Comment: Check data types assigned to source and transformer connectors.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Rhino message that happens when you use an e4x operator on a variable that isn't an xml object. The following two samples will both throw the same error you are seeing when obj is undefined. Otherwise, 'undefined' in your error will be replaced with obj.toString();

```
// Putting a dot between the variable and () indicates an xml filter
// instead of a function call
obj.('test');

// Two consecutive dots returns all xml descendant elements of obj
// named test instead of retrieving a property named test from obj.
obj..test;
```